# How to have a struts2 form in a table?

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

I am trying to have my form in a table but it generates a table and makes it a mess.
the generated table is as following:

```
 <div>
<s:form action="myaction" >
  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <td><s:textfield name="name" label="Name" /></td>
    <td><s:textfield name="family" label="Family" /></td>
    <td><s:submit/></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
   </s:form>
 </div>
```

Source code :

```
<div>
 <form id="myaction" name="myaction" action="/application/myaction.action" method="post">
        <table class="wwFormTable">   <<<generated table
       <table border="1">
         <tr>
         <td><tr>
                <td class="tdLabel"><label for="Search_Name" class="label">Name:</label></td>
             <td
               ><input type="text" name="Name" value="" id="Search_Name"/></td>
            </tr>
            </td>
          <td><tr>
               <td class="tdLabel"><label for="Search_Family" class="label">Family:</label></td>
         <td
          ><input type="text" name="Family" value="" id="Search_Family"/></td>
      </tr>
      </td>
  <td><tr>
       <td colspan="2"><div align="right"><input type="submit" id="Search_0" value="Submit"/>
         </div></td>
        </tr>
        </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
    </table></form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `"simple"` theme if you do not want to use S2's default `"xhtml"` theme.

You'll lose S2's automatic error reporting. You may wish to consider creating your own theme.

Alternatively, you can use the `"simple"` theme on individual controls.

[See the "Themes and templates" docs to get started](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html).

Comment: does that make any difference ? if I use tile?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use any theme in struts form tag

eg:

```
<s:form action="Courses" theme="css_xhtml">
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><s:textfield name="courseAbbr" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

May Be you should use this code instead...

```
<sp:form >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <sp:textfield name="name"></sp:textfield>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <sp:textfield name="family"></sp:textfield>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <sp:submit/>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</sp:form>
```